# Unable to clone git repo over https with error "fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: L200"

Tags: git, https, clone

We had the problem with Git-server on CentOS behind Nginx reverse proxy.

```
 fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: L200 
 fatal: early
 EOF fatal: index-pack failed
```

Trying to figure out what was going on:

- enabled nginx debug - nothing
- enabled git client debug - nothing
- tried dozens of params to tune at proxy side - keepalive params, buffers params, timeouts, body and tmpfile sizes and nothing again.
- also haven't noticed any problems accessing git server(cloning) directly without proxy and it was a wrong way to debug.
- moreover we've excluded network bandwidth problem and still result...

Answer (score 0):

Later we've noticed that the problem persists only with one particular repository and it was strange...
There were other repos with larger size but without any problems observed.

SOLUTION: Finally this problematic repository we have downloaded via web interface in **zip** format - no errors while downloading, but
we got an error

> "Checksum error in File_name.png. The file is corrupt"  "The archive
> is corrupt"

**while unzipping**. And it was it.

Conclusion - I don't know why we were able to clone it directly bypassing the proxy, but it was **corrupted image file** pushed to repo.